# Binding a TableViewer with a model which is being extended by several other model

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface, eclipse-databinding

I have a class `File` which is being extended by two other classes `CopyFile` and `DeleteFile`.

```
class File {
    private String filePath;
    /** Setters and getters **/
}

class CopyFile {
    private String destinationPath;
    /**setters and getters**/
}

class DeleteFile {
}
```

Now I am trying to bind this to a table viewer:

```
ViewerSupport.bind(tableViewer, new WritableList(realm,
            fileDetailsList, File.class),PojoProperties.values(File.class,
                    new String[] { "filePath","destinationPath"}));
```

I want to show destinationPath when file is an instance of `CopyFile` and `null` or `""` when it is an instance of `DeleteFile`.

But when I am running this it is throwing an error:

> Could not find property with name destinationPath in class File

Please help me out this and tell me how to implement DataBinding in case of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you bind `File.class` the property won't be found since it uses reflection and the property belongs to `CopyFile.class`. binding is done with Beans or POJOs in order to observe their details.